# Passing variables and displaying unique information with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter, and I'm having an issue making URL links and displaying data from a database.

I have a database of one state (Massachusetts). I also have a few cities in Massachusetts (Boston, Brockton, Cambridge and West Newton).

```
My Database is set up like this.
id, state, city,
1   Massachusetts Boston
2   Massachusetts Brockton
3   Massachusetts Cambridge 
4   Massachusetts West Newton
```

My first goal is to display the state of Massachusetts. I accomplished my goal with the syntax below.

My question is: When someone clicks on "Massachusetts," I want to display that state's cities. How would I go about doing so? What's the next step?

My Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){
        $this->load->model('model_data');
        $data["results"] = $this->model_data->getState();
        $this->load->view('view_home',$data); 
    }

}
```

My Model:

```
class Model_data extends CI_Model{

    function getState(){
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->select('state');
        $this->db->order_by('state','ASC');
        $query = $this->db->get('states');
        return $query->result();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach($query->result() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }   
    }

}
```

My View_Home:

```
<?php echo doctype("html5");?>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home View</title>
</head>
<?php
foreach ($results as $row){
    $state = $row->state;
    echo $state.'<br>';
    /*
    Notes to myself: Do I have to pass a URI segment? but do I pass the variable of $state
    */
    echo anchor("",$row->state,array('title'=>$row->state));
}
?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your current database, you can add another method in your `Site` controller to display cities of a state. At first, your link should be this (using the `Site` controller and `getCities` as the method):

```
echo anchor('site/getCities/'.$row->state, $row->state, array('title'=>$row->state));
```

This will generate a link something like this:

```
<a href="http://yourDomain.com/site/getCities/Massachusetts" title="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</a>
```

Or like this one (depending on your `.htaccess` file for URL rewriting):

```
<a href="http://yourDomain.com/index.php/site/getCities/Massachusetts" title="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</a>
```

Now you can add a method in your `Site` controller like:

```
public function getCities($state = null)
{
    if(is_null($state)) return false;
    $this->load->model('Model_data');
    $data['cities'] = $this->getCitiesByState($state);
    $this->load->view('showCities');
}
```

And in your `Model_data` model, add the method `getCitiesByState` to fetch all cities by state name:

```
public function getCitiesByState($state)
{
    // load database if not autoloaded
    // assumed, your table name is cities
    $query = $this->db->get_where('cities', array('state' => $state));
    if($query->num_rows()) return $query->result();
    return null;
}
```

Then in the view (showCities.php):

```
if(isset($cities) && !is_null($cities))
{
    echo "Cities of " . $cities[0]->state . "<br />";
    foreach ($cities as $city)
    {
        echo $city->id . " " . $city->city . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: @mscmsc - If you liked his answer, it would be nice of you to accept it.

Comment: @PédeLeão how would I do that? I tried to "vote up" his response but I couldn't. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

$query = $this->db->get('states') - shouldn't it be  $query = $this->db->get('state')

foreach ($results as $row){
$state = $row->state->city;
echo $state

and either edit your function to get the city, or create another function to get the city for the state. Or, change your Database tables all together and join tables by ID and echo out the city for the match ID.